# How to suppress a connection between two nodes in TCL language

Tags: ns2

I have been looking for it for a while in various tutorials and all I can find is the syntax for creating a connection between 2 existing nodes `n1` and `n2` i.e

`$ns duplex-link $n1 $n2 10Mb 10ms DropTail`

But my need now is to delete at a particular moment (say t = 5s) the connection between them.
I've thought about hacking the previous syntax by setting the bandwidth of the existing connection to 0, like this:

`$ns at 5. "$ns duplex-link $n1 $n2 0Mb 10ms DropTail"`

I think this should do the trick, at least theoretically, but I wonder if there is no better way, built-in way to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right way for doing it

```
$ns rtmodel-at 5. down $n1 $n2
```

[Source](http://www.engr.iupui.edu/~dskim/tutorials/print.php?article=ns2)